# Function pointer in a struct with same argument type

Tags: c, struct, function-pointers

I am trying to make a struct which has a function pointer for a function that takes the same struct as an argument. I have this at the moment.

```
typedef struct sharedData
{
    sem_t* forks;
    int id;
    void (*forkFunc)(sharedData*);
};
```

I am getting errors like

> error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token

and warnings like

```
 warning: no semicolon at end of struct or union 
 warning: useless storage class specifier in empty declaration
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you mean to write struct sharedData* instead?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that when you're using `typedef struct` to introduce a new `struct` that doesn't require the `struct` keyword, you cannot refer to the `typedef`-ed name inside the declaration of the `struct`.  Instead, you need to use the full name for the struct.  For example:

```
typedef struct sharedData
{
    sem_t* forks;
    int id;
    void (*forkFunc)(struct sharedData*);
};
```

Also, your `typedef` statement is currently invalid because you haven't given a name by which to call `struct sharedData`.  One way to fix this would be as follows:

```
typedef struct sharedData
{
    sem_t* forks;
    int id;
    void (*forkFunc)(struct sharedData*);
} sharedData;
```

Now, you can refer to the struct by the full name `struct sharedData` or by the shorthand name `sharedData`.

Comment: Drop the final underscore; it's just ugly and useless. Using the same name for the struct tag and typedef is perfectly valid.

Comment: @R..- Cool!  I didn't know that.  Will update my original post.